# QGrapicsView центрирование вида

Tags: qt

QGraphicsView центрирует вид на QGraphicsScene таким образом, что бы сцена помещалась ровно в центре вьювера, то есть так:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

А хотелось бы, что бы сцена всегда была привязана в верхнему левому углу:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Покопавшись в документации так ничего и не понял, помогите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить alignment:

```
view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
```

Comment: Спасибо) помогло)